# Юзер-агент для парсинга

Tags: веб-программирование

Я заметил, что если использовать мобильный юзер агент, то парсинг/скрейпинг делать легче, так как структура html простая и легко достать контент. + я заметил что андроидовский браузер Via умеет в некоторых случаях получать уже готовый html, созданный js скриптом. Например, эта ссылка -> http://idwl.cn/file/434258/Brooklyn.Nine-Nine.S04E22.720p.SunshineStudio.mkv_480p_800x450.mp4.html Там ссылка на загрузку деобфусцируется скриптом JS в Via сама. Если использовать другой юзер агент, то ссылки не будут и надо деобфуцировать ручками. Сам юзер агент вот

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Q415 Build/MOB31K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Можете обьяснить почему так?

Comment: Значит сайт который вы парсите выдает разный контент в зависимости от useragent.

Comment: @Visman, но они же не зря сделали обфускацию.. Зачем им это?

Comment: Может Uppod плеер по разному у них работает на разных платформах, если вы про ссылку на видео ведете речь.